# What are best practices for partitioning DocumentDB across accounts?

Tags: partitioning, sharding, azure-cosmosdb

I am developing an application that uses DocumentDB to store customer data. One of the requirements is that we segregate customer data by geographic region, so that US customers' data is stored within the US, and European customers' data lives in Europe.

The way I planned to achieve this is to have two DocumentDB accounts, since an account is associated with a data centre/region. Each account would then have a database, and a collection within that database.

I've reviewed the DocumentDB documentation on client- and server-side partitioning (e.g. [1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sharding/), [2](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-partition-data/)), but it seems to me that the built-in partitioning support will not be able to deal with multiple regions. Even though an implementation of `IPartitionResolver` could conceivably return an arbitrary collection self-link, the partition map is associated with the `DocumentClient` and therefore tied to a specific account.

Therefore it appears I will need to create my own partitioning logic and maintain two separate `DocumentClient` instances - one for the US account and one for the Europe account. Are there any other ways of achieving this requirement?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but the upcoming global database support in DocumentDB (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/documentdb-goes-planet-scale-with-global-databases-new-pricing-and-more-developer-choices/) might be what you need!

Comment: Thanks, I don't think it is though - I looked into it when it was first announced, and it seems that it's more about replication than segregation. In my case, I want to keep data in a specific region, but query across both occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure's [best practices on data partitioning](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/best-practices-data-partitioning/) says:

> All databases are created in the context of a DocumentDB account. A
>   single DocumentDB account can contain several databases, and it
>   specifies in which region the databases are created. Each DocumentDB
>   account also enforces its own access control. You can use DocumentDB
>   accounts to geo-locate shards (collections within databases) close to
>   the users who need to access them, and enforce restrictions so that
>   only those users can connect to them.

So, if your intention is to keep the data near to user (and not just keep them stored separate) your only option is to create different accounts.  Lucky that billing is not per account based but per collection based.

DocumentDB's [resource model](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-resources/#hierarchical-resource-model) gives an impression that you can not (atleast out of the box) mix DocumentDB accounts.  It doesn't look like partition keys are of any use too as partitions too can happen only within the same account.

May be this [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Geo-location-types-with-d3ea05a2) would help you or give some hints.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I'd figured, but I wanted a sanity check! It'd be nice if this feature ended up in the client SDK at some point :)